# Android Studio: 2 different activities in 1 button

Tags: java, php, mysql, android-studio, android-volley

I want to make the login button to dispatch into 2 different activities using the flag column on the database??

[image]

if the tenant logged in it will redirect to the tenant activity

and when the landlord is logged in it will redirect to the other activity?

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                // Check for error node in json
                if (success == 1) {


                    String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                    String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                    Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                    editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                    editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    editor.commit();

                    // go to main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                    intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: you can add if statement and use intent in it accoding to the condition

Comment: java? php? please dont tag spam

Comment: @DheerajJoshi where and what condition should i put on to it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the onClickListener() method of your `log in` button,you can put a `if()` statement.

**Steps To Do this**

**1.** Get the data from the username and password field and use that in your query to retrieve the data from the database

**2.** Store the data you retrieved in a String like below because you will get only one row:

`String flag = cursor.getString(7); //skipping the cursor and other database part`

**3.** Now you can put the if() statement in the onClickListener of login button after getting the `String flag` value like:

```
if(flag.equals(landlord)){
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Landlord.class);
 startActivity(intent);
}
else{
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,Tenant.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow you will be querying to verify username & password, at the same time you could also fetch the flag information and store it in locally(reduces the database calls).

Store those data in a map with key as username (Assumption username will be unique) and flag as value.

```
Map<String,String> mapToRouting = new Map<String,String>();
```

Now for routing different activities, inside the button click method try like

```
public static void buttonClickMethod(){
   //textFieldUserName is the username of user trying to login
  if(isLanlord(textFieldUserName)){
     //this means user is Landlord & put code to redirect to corresponding screen
  }
  else{
     //put code to which redirects to tenants screen!
  }

}
```

Method to find whether the user is landlor or not.

```
public static void isLandlord(String userName){
  boolean result = false;
      if(mapToRouting.get(userName).equalsIgnorecase("Landlord"))
          result = true;
  return result;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful.